# Need to replace a specific column value of a file based on values in other columns of the file

Tags: perl, shell, unix, nawk

Below is my content of file and below is my requirement
Based value in column no 1 and column no 5, I would want to replace value in column 7 with "1".

For example:

1. If column 1="change" and column 5="defer", then replace value in column 7 with "1".
2. If column 1="change" and column 5="defererence" then replace value in column 7 with "1".
3. Otherwise do not do anything with row, keep it as it is.

Input file:

```
Change|sinmg|1234|ewfew|def|fdfd|JAMES|rewr|ROBERT|3|fe
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
noChange|sinmg|2323|ewfew|def|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|fe
Change|sinmg|3456|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defererence|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
```

Above is just a sample to make it easier to explain.However I want to pass values for column 1 and column 5 from a file to match against value in file. If it matches, then only replace column 7 with value "1" otherwise dont do anything with row, keep it as it is.

I tried couple of options and not able to achieve required results.

```
perl -F'\|' -i -lape  'if ($F[0] eq "change" && $F[4] eq "defer") { s/$F[6]/1/g;}' file_name
```

Above command is replacing all values of 3 in file irrespective of fields. But i want to only replace 6th column value based on 1st column and 4th column by passing different values to 1st and 4th column in a loop.

**Adding more information:**

As mentioned by me above, above example is just simplest form of my problem to make everybody understand the requirement. I have a file with name "listfile" which has got list of values for column no 1 and column no 5 for matching. If values in column no 1 and column no 5 from my sourcefile matches with the values passed from file "listfile", then solution should replace value in column no 7 with "1". Otherwise do not do anything with row from source file, keep it as it is.

I tried to do below, but unable to achieve required.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    for line in $(cat dir/listfile)
    do
    VAR1=$(echo $line | nawk -F"|" '{print $1}')
    VAR2=$(echo $line | nawk -F"|" '{print $2}')
    nawk -F"|" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {if($1!="'"$VAR1"'" && $5!="'"$VAR2"'") {$8="1"; print $0;}      else {print $0;}}' dir/sourcefile >> dir/sourcefile_REVISED
    done
```

No of records between original source file and revised source file after replacing Column no 7 should be same. Only thing is for all values of Column no 1 and 5 from file listfile, i need column no 7 value to be replaced by "1".

Thanks,

Comment: To clarify, the replacement is "1", not the first column !

Comment: @iamauser the 1 is quoted to mean the literal value 1, the seventh column contains numeric data and the attempted script `s/$F[6]/1/g` use a literal 1 so it's pretty clear.

Comment: @sudo_O OK, thanks. My initial answer was with first column, but changed after looking at the question more carefully :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do this.

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{if($1=="Change"&&$5=="defer"){$7=1}{print}}' file
```

I realize that you also need 5th column to match with "differerence"... Following should work:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{if($1=="Change"&&$5=="defer"||$5=="defererence"){$7=1}{print}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'\|' -i -lape '
  BEGIN{ $" = "|" }
  $F[6]=1, $_="@F" if $F[0] eq "Change" && $F[4] =~ /^defer(erence)?$/;
' listfile
```

Comment: @mpapec Can you please describe a bit how this works? I could only understand `if $F[0] eq "Change" && $F[4] =~ /^defer(erence)?$/` portion. I would like to learn such concise style of scripting.

Comment: @jkshah `$F[6]=1` replaces value in seventh cokumn, and `$_="@F"` makes new line of values separeted by `|`

Answer (score 0):

The substitute operator `s///` doesn't understand the concept of columns of data, it just operates on the given string.  In this case, you are replacing whatever is in column 7 **everywhere** it occurs in the input line because of the `g` modifier.

The `awk` solution in the answer by @imauser is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you would do:

```
$ awk '$1=="Change"&&$5~/^defer(erence)?$/{$7=1}1' FS='|' OFS='|' file
Change|sinmg|1234|ewfew|def|fdfd|JAMES|rewr|ROBERT|3|fe
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|3|
noChange|sinmg|2323|ewfew|def|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|fe
Change|sinmg|3456|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|3|
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defererence|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a perl+regexp solution by "skipping" the first six fields before doing the replacement:

```
perl -F'\|' -i -lapE  'if ($F[0] eq "change" && $F[4] =~ m{^defer(erence)?$}) { s{^(?:[^|]*\|){6}\K([^|]*)}{1} }' file_name
```

An advantage over the awk solutions: you can still use the `-i` switch here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `split` and `join` in `perl` script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile = "dir/sourcefile";
my $listfile = "dir/listfile";
my $outfile = "dir/sourcefile_REVISED";

my @list;
open LFOPEN, $listfile or die $!;
while (<LFOPEN>) {
    chomp;
    my @col = split /\|/, $_;
    push @list, \@col;
}
close LFOPEN;

open IFOPEN, $infile or die $!;
open OFOPEN, '>', $outfile or die $!;
while (<IFOPEN>) {
    chomp;
    my @col = split /\|/, $_;
    foreach my $lref (@list) {
        $col[6] = '1' if ($col[0] eq $lref->[0] and $col[4] eq $lref->[1]);
    }
    print OFOPEN join ('|', @col) . "\n";
}
close IFOPEN;
close OFOPEN;
```

Input (dir/sourcefile):

```
Change|sinmg|1234|ewfew|def|fdfd|JAMES|rewr|ROBERT|3|fe
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
noChange|sinmg|2323|ewfew|def|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|fe
Change|sinmg|3456|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defererence|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|
```

List (dir/listfile):

```
Change|defer
Change|defererence
```

Output (dir/sourcefile_REVISED):

```
Change|sinmg|1234|ewfew|def|fdfd|JAMES|rewr|ROBERT|3|fe
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|3
noChange|sinmg|2323|ewfew|def|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|3|rewr|BEAEY|3|fe
Change|sinmg|3456|ewfew|defer|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|3
Change|sinmg|2345|ewfew|defererence|VENKTRAAAMMAMAMAMMAMA|1|rewr|BEAEY|3
```

Comment: Don't use global filehandles, use 3 form one instead like : `open my $fh, ">", $file or die $!;`

Comment: @sputnick Thanks for your feedback but didn't get you. `use 3 form one ??` - can you please elaborate a little or provide reference link?

Comment: Your `open` don't pass `perlcritic -5 file`, this is Perl Best-Practices : `file.pl: Bareword file handle opened at line 3, column 1.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5, Policy: InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles)
`

Comment: @sputnick Now I get it, will take care next time. I am curious even if we properly open and close bareword filehandles, is there a risk?

Comment: Run `perlcritic -4 script.pl` yourself, it will tell you. I think 4 is a good level, less is too annyoning/discutable.